# How do use the results of NDSolve in the definition of another function?

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I'm trying to plot a function of x and t in 1D, using manipulate to step through the time evolution of the function.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Norm[χ[x, t]]^2, {x, -10, 10} ], 
  {t, 0, 1.82}]
```

I have defined the function

```
χ[x_, t_] := 
  E^{
      I[.5*(x - Evaluate[q[t] /. sol])^2 (Evaluate[a[t] /. sol] + 
      I Evaluate[b[t] /. sol]) + Evaluate[p[t] /. sol] (x -Evaluate[q[t] /. sol])]}
```

where `a`, `b`, `q`, `p` are time dependent functions that have been found using `NDSolve`,

```
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {q'[t] == -p[t]/m, 
     p'[t] == -E^(-1/(4 b[t])) Sin[q[t]],  
     b'[t] == 2 a[t]/m,  
     a'[t] == (a[t]^2 - b[t]^2)/m + E^(-1/(4 b[t])) Cos[q[t]],  
     q[0] == 0, p[0] == 1, a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1}, 
    {q, p, a, b}, {t, 0 , 10}]
```

It's not clear to me from the documentation if this is the proper syntax for Evaluate or /.sol in this context. Manipulate does not return any kind of error, it just returns a blank plot.

Comment: I've set m=1 in a previous line. NDSolve returns q,p,a,b and I can plot those individually as functions of time with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, while defining chi, what you should be using is

```
\[Chi][x_,t_]:=E^(I(.5*(x-Evaluate[q[t]/.sol])^2 (Evaluate[a[t]/.sol]+I Evaluate[b[t]/.sol])+Evaluate[p[t]/.sol] (x-Evaluate[q[t]/.sol])))
```

You have used `[ and {` brackets where you should be using `(`. `I [1]` is different from `I (1)`.

You could have figured it out by trying to find what `\[Chi][1,1]` gives you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to rewrite your definition of χ[x_, t].

```
 χ[x_, t_] := 
    E^I ((x - q[t])^2 (a[t]/2 + I b[t]) + p[t] (x - q[t]))
```

Note: the Wolfram Language only allows parentheses `( )` for grouping sub-expressions in an expression.

Second, I strongly suggest using `NDSolveValue` in place of `NDSolve`.

```
 Clear[q, p, b, a]
 {q, p, b, a} =
   With[{m = 100.},
     NDSolveValue[
       {q'[t] == -p[t]/m,
        p'[t] == -E^(-1/(4 b[t])) Sin[q[t]],
        b'[t] == 2 a[t]/m, 
        a'[t] == (a[t]^2 - b[t]^2)/m + E^(-1/(4 b[t])) Cos[q[t]],
       q[0] == 0, p[0] == 1, a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1},
       {q, p, a, b}, {t, 0, 10}]];
```

Note: I have selected an arbitrary value for `m` because you didn't give one.

Then

```
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Norm[χ[x, t]]^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2*^4}}],
  {t, 0, 10, ,5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

will give you a look at the behavior of `χ` over the domain `{x, -10, 10}` for various values of `t`.

[image: demo]